# Как удалить class кликнув вне кнопки?

Tags: javascript

Я хочу сделать так что бы classList.remove срабатывал по клику вне элемента т.е в данном случае всё что не кнопка ...

В данный момент я добавляю и удаляю класс при клике на кнопку а я хочу удалить class по клику где попало

Пробовал так :

```js
var sea = document.querySelector("#search");
var btn = document.querySelector("#forsearch");

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const target = e.target;
  target === sea ? "active" : target !== btn ? remove() : false;
});

btn.onclick = function() {
  if (sea.classList.contains('active')) {
    sea.classList.remove("active");
  } else {
    sea.classList.add("active");
  }
};
```

```css
#search {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  transition: 0.34s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#search.active {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.form-wrapper {
  width: 320px;
  display: flex;
}

button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  user-select: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="search">
  <button id="forsearch"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/23906/hubfs/search-home.png?width=4128&name=search-home.png" alt="" style="width:20px;"></button>
</div>
```

Не работает вот это

```
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
const target = e.target;
  target === sea ? "active" : target !== btn ? remove() : false;
});
```

Как можно исправить ситуацию ?

Comment: `input` - тоже не кнопка. Как его использовать, если он скроется?

Comment: @РустамГимранов хм... я имел ввиду удалить class="active" у input

Comment: При потере фокуса `blur` самого `input`, проще удалить класс.

Comment: @РустамГимранов если можно покажите пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var sea = document.querySelector('#search');
var btn = document.querySelector('#forsearch');

// По щелчку на кнопке,
// добавляем класс к полю ввода.
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (!sea.classList.contains('active')) {
    sea.classList.add('active');
  }
})

// По окнчанию анимации,
// cтавим принудительно focus.
sea.addEventListener('transitionend', function(event) {
  sea.focus();
})

// При потере фокуса,
// удаляем класс `active` у input.
sea.addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
  sea.classList.remove('active');
})
```

```css
#search {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  transition: 0.34s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#search.active {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.form-wrapper {
  width: 320px;
  display: flex;
}

button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  user-select: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="search" autofocus>
  <button type="button" id="forsearch"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/23906/hubfs/search-home.png?width=4128&name=search-home.png" alt="" style="width:20px;"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much :))

Comment: а вот эта штука "transitionend" это что такое ?

Comment: Событие, когда анимация [оканчивается](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-transitions#sobytie-transitionend)

Comment: Если бы у `#search` не было `transition: 0.34s;`, то фокус на `input` можно было бы сразу поставить после клика на кнопку. А так приходится дождаться окончания анимации (увеличение ширины, прозрачность в вашем случае).

Comment: я понял ..просто не видел раньше transitionend , оказывается это штука тоже есть ...js на самом деле силён в своих возможностях ...